# How does one download a pdf from a URL in Python and Convert it to Fulltext (HTML/Dictionary for dataset passthrough)?

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-extraction

I am using the following pdf as an example:

http://www.courts.wa.gov/content/publicUpload/Supreme%20Court%20Orders/Jury%20Resumption%20Order%20061820.pdf

How in python would I remotely download this pdf locally; convert it to fulltext either in HTML or into a python dictionary for input into an external database such as MySQL?

I was planning on using [dataset](https://dataset.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for the pass through to MySQL.

Has anyone succeeded with this?

Thank you!

~ Brandon

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. You should give an example what you have tried and where your exact problem is. Please look into [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Thank you ChristianB; I will do my best to contribute more!

Comment: Sorry I posted the wrong link. Here is the right one: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: ChristianB, no problem! I read it anyways!